# getting data from firebase database by userId

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from my database firebase, but I get no data to show in list item html because I pushed `UserId` first in database.

[image]

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(,public fire: AngularFireAuth,public db: AngularFireDatabase) 
    {
        this.itemsRef = db.list('report/');
        // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
        this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(changes => 
            changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
          )
        );


      }
```

you can see here no data to show in list item

[image]

html

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items | async"> 
    <ion-item-sliding>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{item.username}}</p>
        <p>{{item.dateadded}}</p>
    </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="right"> 
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletReport(item.key)">
          <ion-icon  ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash" item-end large></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="updatereport(item.key,item.name,item.title)">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: your node structure in firebase database is confusing because if you already have userid in the parent node which can uniquely identify the user node then why you create another id inside the userid node, simply remove that useless id and your code will work fine

Comment: i dont have another id inside the userid node ,

Comment: I am talking about this id "LWFnfe....." inside the userid node "VHa088......"